# Метод с параметрами

Tags: c#

```
public int розничная(int экз, int общ, int тираж)
        { 
            if (экз < 50)
            {
                return cost(общ, тираж) + ((cost(общ, тираж) * 25) / 100);
            } else
            if (экз < 51 && экз<100)
            {
                return cost(общ, тираж) + ((cost(общ, тираж) * 15) / 100);
            }else
            if (экз > 100)
            {
                return cost(общ, тираж) + ((cost(общ, тираж) * 5) / 100);
            }
        }
```

Вылазит ошибка. Изначально было:

```
public int розничная(int экз, int общ, int тираж)
        {
            int r;
            if (экз < 50)
            {
                r= cost(общ, тираж) + ((cost(общ, тираж) * 25) / 100);
            } else
            if (экз < 51 && экз<100)
            {
                r = cost(общ, тираж) + ((cost(общ, тираж) * 15) / 100);
            }else
            if (экз > 100)
            {
                r = cost(общ, тираж) + ((cost(общ, тираж) * 5) / 100);
            }
            return r;
        }
```

Но так тоже ошибка. С методами с параметрами сталкиваюсь впервые. Подскажите в чём ошибка?

Comment: какая ошибка-то?

Comment: @kazz название в кириллице у вас можно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашей функции указан тип возвращающего значения `int`.
В новой функции вы убрали ключевое слово `return` из-за этого получаете ошибку.

Для исправления (на выбор):

1. Добавьте строку `return 0;` в конце метода.
2. Исправьте последний `else if` на просто `else`